# Как привести к первоначальному формату Map после применения entrySet() в Stream API?

Tags: java, типы-данных, java-stream

Мне нужно применить к `Map` `.filter()`, для этого нужен stream, следовательно применяю `.entrySet()`, но после данное выражение имеет тип `Entry<Map<key , value>>`. Подскажите, как мне привести это обратно к  `Map<key , value>`

Вот полная строка кода:
`countryMap = countryMap.entrySet().stream().filter((x) -> x.getKey().equals(country));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    countryMap.entrySet().stream()               
                  .filter((x) -> x.getKey().equals(country))
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue))
```